# Convert radians to degrees like Google

Tags: c++, math

Im trying to convert radians to degrees, but im not getting the same results as google

calculator and the Pi i defined dosent output all number.

If you type in google search: **(1 * 180) / 3.14159265** then you get **57.2957796**, but my program is

outputting: **57.2958** and if you type in google search Pi you get: **3.14159265**, but mine

dosent output the rest, it output: **3.14159**

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#define SHOW(X) cout << # X " = " << (X) << endl

using namespace std;

double Pi_test = 3.14159265;

float radian_to_degree(double  ENTER) {
  double Pi = 3.14159265;
  float degrees = (ENTER * 180) / Pi;
  return degrees;
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    SHOW( radian_to_degree(1) ); // 57.2958 not 57.2957795 like google, why?
    SHOW( Pi_test ); // output 3.14159' not 3.14159265, why? 
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me fix this, what wrong? any example?

Comment: Why is your function returning `float`?

Comment: I dident know the best unit to use..

Comment: Doubles have 'double' the precision of floats. If you're writing math functions then make them generic by using templates.

Comment: Quick google search found the answer ("stop c++ rounding")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100414062510AAjshrv), it may be that `cout` in C++ is rounding your number before displaying it. Try this:

```
#define SHOW(X) cout << setprecision(some_number) << # X " = " << (X) << endl
```

Comment: Hmm, my answer might be incorrect... I'm not exactly a C expert, ha. Do the others work for you?

Answer (score 8):

You need to change the default precision:

```
cout.precision(15);
cout << d << endl;
```

Comment: And return a double as properly noted by Pubby.

Comment: All that is happening is that the answer is rounded to a certain decimal, and J.Ns code should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Change `radian_to_degree` to operate on `double` not `float`, since `double` has more precision.

Output the result using `std::setprecision`

```
#include <iomanip>
std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << result << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after you change `cout`'s precision, note that `double` only contains so much data; if you expect your program to spit out 1000 decimal places, a `double` is not going to give you that much. You'd have to create a data type of your own.

Also, don't define macro functions unless you have to.